# NodeJS: Why do installation instructions always say to use NPM install -g (global)?

Tags: node.js, unix, npm

See for example: https://npmjs.org/package/generator-meteor

Almost all installation instructions involving `npm` say to use `npm install -g`. Why would I want everything to be installed globally instead of just for my current *nix user?

Answer (score 3):

> instead of just for my current *nix user

In this context local means "just one node application", not "just for my user". Respectively, global means "for all node applications", not "for all users on this computer".

NPM modules which are installed globally usually implement functionality that you would use across applications, and not just in one project. One example is a command-line tool. You install the npm package globally and that provides you with a way to invoke a command from your OS's terminal. Since this doesn't make sense in just one application, you have to install it in the global NPM location. Of course you need to make sure that the module really needs to work across applications before installing it.

The generator that you've linked is used by Yeoman, which is a command-line tool for scaffolding applications. Hence the global need.

Comment: But `npm install -g` requires superuser privileges. Why does it need superuser privileges if it's just installing for the current user?

Answer (score 0):

When you do `npm install` in a directory where a package.json is located, npm creates a node_modules folder and puts in it all the project package needings.

When you do `npm install -g` the installed package(s) goes to `/usr/lib/node_modules/` making them available globally. (-g stands for 'global') and allowing CLI implementations. Like express (as in `express --sessions project`, wich is not available without installing express globally)

Almost every tutorial requires global installations because they use CLI stuff or you'll use them later, so is better for you to have them installed.